# Datatables count value in specific column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables to display data to my users. When a specific column in row contains a specific value (the status is AP, o Awaiting Processing) I set the row to have a red background color.

So far, all good.

Now, I also want to calculate how many entries in the whole table that has this status. This is what each column contains (some are not Awaiting Processing, of course):

```
<span class='text-danger' data-toggle='popover' data-content='Awaiting processing'>AP</span>
```

So, what I do, is I look for ">AP<" when I set the background with:

```
"createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                    if (data[6].includes(">AP<")) {
                        $(row).addClass('table-danger');
                    }
                }
```

After this, I try to get the total with:

```
            var apFound = tResults.columns(6).data().filter(function (value, index) {
                return value.includes(">AP<");
            }).length;
            
            $("#countAP").html(apFound);
```

This refuses to work. I have tried multiple approaches after extensive Googling, but it never works. Always returns 0;

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This can be simple as:

```js
console.log($("span[data-content='Awaiting processing']").length);

console.log($("span:contains('AP')").length);

console.log(document.querySelectorAll("span[data-content='Awaiting processing']").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class='text-danger' data-toggle='popover' data-content='Awaiting processing'>AP</span><br>
<span class='text-danger' data-toggle='popover' data-content='Awaiting processing'>AP</span><br>
<span class='text-danger' data-toggle='popover' data-content='Awaiting processing'>AP</span><br>
<span class='text-danger' data-toggle='popover' data-content='NOT processing'>NOT</span>
```

Or you can even use this to add class to it and make count right away:

```js
var count=0;    
[...document.querySelectorAll("span[data-content='Awaiting processing']")].forEach(element => {
    element.classList.add("table-danger"); 
    count=count+1;
  });
console.log(count);
```

```css
.table-danger {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class='text-danger' data-toggle='popover' data-content='Awaiting processing'>AP</span><br>
<span class='text-danger' data-toggle='popover' data-content='Awaiting processing'>AP</span><br>
<span class='text-danger' data-toggle='popover' data-content='Awaiting processing'>AP</span><br>
<span class='text-danger' data-toggle='popover' data-content='NOT processing'>NOT</span>
```

Comment: Nice approach, but it only counts the entries on the current page. If I have other "Awaiting Processing" items on other pages (say, page 3)  they are not counted.

Comment: @RobertBenedetto You are right, that crossed my mind. You should make [mre], with dummy data and working snippet example. Pretty sure this is fairly easy to do what you need. Its hard to guess for anyone one without seeing example with data. You can load data-tables from CDN and attach dummy data in snippet...